# JFrog invalid access token when pushing docker image

Tags: docker, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm having an issue where I can't push docker images with JFrog CLI:

This works:

```
docker login -u <username> --password <ACCESS_TOKEN> <URL>
docker tag my_img:latest <url>/<repository>/my_image:latest
docker push <url>/<repository>/my_image:latest
```

However

```
jf config add --interactive=false --user <username> --url <URL> --access_token <ACCESS_TOKEN> myServer
docker tag my_img:latest <url>/<repository>/my_image:latest
jf use myServer
jf docker push <url>/<repository>/my_image:latest --server-id myServer
```

gives me an error:

> [Error] received invalid access-token

I would expect that those two are equivalent.

I also tried a couple of variations - to the same effect:

```
jf docker push image_name/latest <repository>/image_name:latest --server-id myServer

jf rt dp my_image/latest <repository>/my_image:latest
```

To make thing even weirder, the same jf config works fine for conan:

```
jf config use myServer
jf rt upload <path>/<artifact> <conan_repository>/<artifact>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I am suspecting that the CLI call is running into a similar issue as reported [here](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/1579).

Instead of using an [identity token](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-identity-tokens-expire-earlier-than-expected/#:%7E:text=What%20are%20Identity,Access%20Tokens.) created from the user profile section, can you please try using an [Access Token](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Access+Tokens) generated under the following path?

**JFrog Platform UI -> Administration -> User management -> Access Token**?

Comment: Very likely!! Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @ventsyv you can still your identity token, just use it as a password instead of as an access token, by replacing "--access-token" with "--password"